# Delete id if not in database from a value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to check the ids of the values that exist in the database. I know how to check if a single id exists, but I don't know how to check multiple ids. If there is an id that does not exist from database then delete non existing id in the value.

For example: `$value = '1,2,3,4,6,7,8';` so check this ids from database if 2 and 3 is not exist from database and remove those ids in the value `$value = '1,4,5,6,7,8';`

*Note: I just want to remove non existing id from value not from database.*

Comment: do a query to get rows for all those ids, and then filter out ids for which there are corresponding rows and for rest of the ids run a delete query.

Comment: How do you check if single ID exists? A sample would be helpful to help you. Basically for database you need use: `IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` then do a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') AS `ids` FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,6,7,8);
```

The above query returns a result which shows only the existing id. update `table name, id field` and `input string` as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

Then you compare arrays:

```
$value = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
$value = array_intersect($value,$values_from_database);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array intersect will remove values from your array that are not in the second comparison array. `remove those ids in the value $value = '1,4,5,6,7,8';`

```php
$values = array(1,4,5,6,7,8);
// say your DB array has the following values in it. 
$row = array(1,4,5,7);
// We run them both through array_intersect...
$result = array_intersect($values, $row);
// Now reassign $values as the $result array. 
$values = $result;
```

`var_dump($values)` outputs: 
`array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(4) [2]=> int(5) [4]=> int(7) }`